# UFW: Translating iptables rule to UFW

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ufw

This is the iptables rule:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.2.0.51,10.2.0.52 -d 228.0.0.3 -j ACCEPT
```

How can I translate it to ufw rule?

I´ve tried:

```
root@localhost:~# sudo ufw allow from 10.2.0.51,10.2.0.,52 to 228.0.0.3 to any port
ERROR: Wrong number of arguments

root@localhost:~# sudo ufw allow from 10.2.0.51,10.2.0,52 to 228.0.0.3 to any port proto tcp
ERROR: Wrong number of arguments
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is following:

```
sudo ufw allow from <target> to <destination> port <port number> proto <protocol name>
```

so, you should run

```
sudo ufw allow from 10.2.0.51,10.2.0.52 to 228.0.0.3
```

it will allow all ports and all protocols. For TCP only:

```
sudo ufw allow from 10.2.0.51,10.2.0.52 to 228.0.0.3 proto tcp
```